# Ubuntu 20.04 Web server will not received forwarded internet web traffic from router

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dns

I am currently having issue redoing my local webserver.

The primary issue is that it no longer serves anything to the internet, but will serve on the local LAN just fine.

Originally (about a year ago) I setup a local web server with Ubuntu Server 20.04 to run docker container applications I am developing. All the apps are microservices so I had no need for hosting anything publicly (as that would come later, i.e. now), but I still went through the process of:

- paying for a domain (from namecheap)
- got the dns redirection setup to my public ip address
- getting ubuntu setup with a static IP address and communicating on the LAN
- getting port forwarding setup in the router for exposing the web server to the internet (ports 80 & 443).
  the services I have been running for the last year only pull info from the web, dont host. But I wanted to configure a web application for hosting so I didnt have to go through a bunch of work.

Originally I just had Apache running on ubuntu, and got to the point I was able to type in my domain eg: "mydomain.com" and it would show the default apache web page.
All was well, and I left it there until I actually needed to host a web application.

However, within the last year, I have had to migrate the server to new hardware, and also installed a new Asus router and had to make an overhaul to my local network for reasons.
So instead of my local ip's being 192.168.x.x I switched to 10.0.x.x.
I now have gotten a Docker web app service up and running as a demo website that can be accessed within my LAN from 10.0.#.#:80. So I know the website is active 100%.

Everything else is running fine, but for some reason I cannot get Ubuntu to repond to an external domain request, and I know 100% it is directing to my public IP. even if I use my public ip "1.2.3.4:80", it still doesnt work. However, the hosting and network of web stuff is my weakest knowledge base.
I have recently uninstalled Apache as it was causing issues with the ports of my docker containers, but I assume I dont need apache.

My current temporary solution is to use OpenVPN and just use the web app with my LAN ips.

When I did the migration all the configs and original settings were copied, and I am guessing that I did not change one of the Ubuntu configurations from the original 192.168.#.# to the new 10.0.#.# ip of the server. As I was not using Ubuntu server all that often and it has been a year since I actually got it work, I have completely forgotten all the configurations for exposing ips/ports to the router.
ufw is inactive, and I dont believe I have any other firewalls configured (for now). And I have been searching tutorials and guides online but none have lead to any settings or configs that arent changed to match my current network.

So my questions:

- Is there a config file that I could have forgotten (i can post any needed)?
- I would assume I would not need Nginx or Apache running if I already have Docker Containers handling serving the web application. But do would I actually need a server application to take in the traffic and send it to Docker?

Comment: If it serves on the LAN, then it works. Kudos for testing that! Seems like you have isolated the problem to your router's port forwarding.

Comment: I concur with @user535733. You will need to confirm on your router whether the correct ports are being forwarded or if your web server is in the DMZ 